# Namespace + class naming collisions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to organize my MVC project all nice-like, but had issues with naming collisions, and wondered if there is a better solution than having to rename things to not-as-logical names.

I.E., in my Application.Model.Entities namespace exists the 'User' class.

Then I've got Application.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.User, the namespace in which I was going to place all of my User-related models. This causes a naming collision, and when I attempt to instantiate a User object, it informs me that namespaces aren't classes.

I understand why the error is happening, I'm just curious if there is a solution better than renaming my MVC model folders. (Which I can do - I can have ProgramViewModels, ProgramWhateverModels, etc. if need be). Just curious!

Answer (score 4):

If you have to use both classes in one namespace f.e. you have class main where you have to use both user classes you may declare something like:

```
using userEnt = Application.Model.Entities;
using userMod = Application.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.User;
```

and next just call userEnt.User and userMod.User and there won't be conflicts anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can be more explicit in your instantiations:

Entities.User or Models.User.User instead of just User